# Assigning a shortcut to hide/show multiple particle systems in Blender 2.8

Tags: particles, shortcut

I have a mesh with multiple particle systems.

I try assigning the same shortcut to hide/show them but it doesn't work. The key only works the fist particle system I assigned it too, when logically it should work for all of them at the same time.

Is there a way to quickly hide/show multiple particles systems using a single hotkey?

What am I missing?

Comment: you talking about toggling the viewport visibility of the particle systems, or the particle system modifiers?

Comment: Toggling viewport visibility. It's like the assign shortcut command is broken. If I bind a key to multiple buttons, I expect the key to toggle those buttons.